# command works right in python subprocess when run on terminal but failed when execute in crontab

Tags: python-3.x, macos, cron, nightwatch

I am trying to launch a nightwatch tests daily from crontab.
Everything works fine when I launch my python script on macOS terminal, but once I launch cron job by calling my python script . Error below occurred :

```
"env: node: No such file or directory"
```

I tried to set
Below is the command I try to run from python subprocess:

```
cmd_run =["/usr/local/bin/yarn test /Users/mytest/path/ --tag dbg"]
child_env = os.environ.copy() // inherit shell env setting ? 

with open(full_log, 'w') as fd:
        process=subprocess.Popen(cmd_run, stdout=fd, stderr=fd, shell=True, env=child_env)
```

The actual command I need to run is :

```
E2E_BASEHOST=https://<myhost> E2E_ENV=bk E2E_TESTS_DIRECTORY=./bk/tests **node**  node_modules/nightwatch/bin/runner.js -c ./node_modules/@bk/e2e-testing-configuration/src/nightwatch.conf.js
--group affiliates/bookings2/tests/src/app/ --tag bsb --retries 2
```

I guess it is because subprocess cannot find "node"
I run "which node" on my terminal
It can be find here :

```
/usr/local/bin/node
```

So what is the thing I am missing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put this in your crontab :

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```